# Pytest how to change printing behavior with @pytest.mark.parametrize

Tags: python, pytest

I have a parameterized test that receives a long string as an argument, and the problem is that when executing pytest it prints the entire string

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
"long_string_p1, long_string_p2",
    [
        (a,b) for a,b in zip(list_str_1, list_str_2)
    ]
)

def test_with_long_strings(long_string_p1, long_string_p2):
    # Logic 
    assert long_string_p1 != long_string_p2
```

```bash
pytest 

test_example.py::test_with_long_strings[looooooooong string1-loooooooooong string2] PASSED
```

I would like it to only show the last part of the string, somehow change the logic so that it doesn't show the whole string but only a part

Comment: I suggest reading https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/output.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `pytest.param` to enhance the id values used. Could make a helper to determine the name based on your custom logic.

Here's an example where it strips off the last value in the string and joins them with a dash:

```
import pytest

list_str_1 = ["looooooooong string1"]
list_str_2 = ["loooooooooong string2"]

def make_param(args):
    return pytest.param(*args, id='-'.join([s.split(" ")[-1] for s in args]))


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "long_string_p1, long_string_p2",
    list(map(make_param,  zip(list_str_1, list_str_2)))
)
def test_with_long_strings(long_string_p1, long_string_p2):
    assert long_string_p1 != long_string_p2
```

You can also supply a function as the `ids` argument to format each entry individually:

```
import pytest

list_str_1 = ["looooooooong string1"]
list_str_2 = ["loooooooooong string2"]


def id_function(val):
    return val.split(" ")[-1]

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "long_string_p1, long_string_p2",
    [*zip(list_str_1, list_str_2)],
    ids=id_function
)
def test_with_long_strings(long_string_p1, long_string_p2):
    assert long_string_p1 != long_string_p2
```